# Proof of Baire category theorem in Tao's "Real analysis"

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

In prof Tao's "Real analysis", he proves Baire category theorem as follows:

[image]

I don't understand the highlighted statement. As $x_n \rightarrow x$, for $r_n>0$, there always exists $k \in \mathbb N$ such that the sequence $(x_m)_{m \geq k}$ is in the ball $B(x,r_n)$. But why must $x_n$ be in this sequence, or equivalently $n \geq k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $m>n$ we have $d(x_m,x_{n-1})\le\sum_{k=n}^m d(x_k,x_{k-1})\le \sum_{k=n}^m 2r_{n-1}10^{k-n-1}=(2r_{n-1}/9)(1-10^{-m+n+1})$. Therefore $d(x,x_{n-1})=\lim_{m\to\infty}d(x_m,x_{n-1})\le\lim_{m\to\infty}(2r_{n-1}/9)(1-10^{-m+n+1})=(2r_{n-1}/9)<r_{n-1}$.

Comment: Ah I see, nice!!!